# Insert HLOOKUP formula if cell contains text

Tags: vba, excel

This is how my spreadsheet looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI5jc.png)

I would like to insert a HLOOKUP formula to the cell immediate right of 58DV if the cell contains 58DV. If there is no data, nothing needs to be done. I'm still quite new to VBA so I'm not sure how can i work with formulas in VBA. Thanks

```
Sub sitelookup()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("C4:C1299")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If cel > 0 Then
        cel.Offset(0,1).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLOOKUP(F4,'Raw G'!2:5,2,0)

    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    Set SrchRng = .Range(.cells(4, "B"), .cells(rows.count, "B").end(xlup))

    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If cel.value2 = "58DV" Then
           'to put the formula's value into the neighboring cell
            cel.Offset(0, 1).value = _
               Application.HLOOKUP(.cells(cel.row, "F"), worksheets("Raw G").range("2:5"), 2, 0)
           'to put the formula into the neighboring cell
            'cel.Offset(0, 1).formula = _
               "=HLOOKUP(F" & cel.row & ",'Raw G'!2:5, 2, 0)"
        End If
    Next cel
end with
```